# Removing pages in a pdf file conditioning on something using Python

Tags: python, pdf

I have a PDF file that has around 1000 pages and want to remove some of the pages conditioning on not finding a specific word. For instance, the code would search for a specific word such as "STACKOVER", if it cannot find that word on the page, remove the page and continue to the following page, and at the end saves the file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Next time you post a question, you will need to give more information and show attempts. This will save you a lot of grief. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will be more careful when posting next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is: First, define the search words you are looking for (in my case I tested it on a medical journal and searched for `searchwords=['unclear risk for poorly']`). Second, find all pages containing the word or string and store the page numbers in a list (`pages_to_delete`). For safe keeping, I put them i a csv file giving the page in which a specific searchword is found. Third, open to original pdf, delete the pages contained in the list and save to a new pdf.

```
import PyPDF2
import re
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

pdfFileObj=open(r'C:\Users\s-degossondevarennes\......\dddtest.pdf',mode='rb')
pdfReader=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
number_of_pages=pdfReader.numPages

pages_text=[]
words_start_pos={}
words={}

searchwords=['unclear risk for poorly']

pages_to_delete = []

with open('Pages.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('{0},{1}\n'.format("Sheet Number", "Search Word"))
    for word in searchwords:
        for page in range(number_of_pages):
            print(page)
            pages_text.append(pdfReader.getPage(page).extractText())
            words_start_pos[page]=[dwg.start() for dwg in re.finditer(word, pages_text[page].lower())]
            words[page]=[pages_text[page][value:value+len(word)] for value in words_start_pos[page]]
        for page in words:
            for i in range(0,len(words[page])):
                if str(words[page][i]) != 'nan':
                    f.write('{0},{1}\n'.format(page+1, words[page][i]))
                    pages_to_delete.append(page)
                    

infile = PdfFileReader(r'C:\Users\s-degossondevarennes\.......\dddtest.pdf', 'rb')
output = PdfFileWriter()

for i in range(infile.getNumPages()):
    if i not in pages_to_delete:
        p = infile.getPage(i)
        output.addPage(p)

with open('Newdddtest.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    output.write(f)
```

**Update**

If you want to disregard whether the text is bold or not replace

```
words_start_pos[page]=[dwg.start() for dwg in re.finditer(word, pages_text[page].lower())]
```

with

```
words_start_pos[page]=[dwg.start() for dwg in re.finditer(word, pages_text[page])]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, the code only works for the search word of "unclear risk for poorly". I looked on the web and found your pdf file titled "Assessing Risk of Bias as a Domain of Quality in Medical Test Studies". For instance, when I want to delete the first page of this file by changing your code as searchwords=['Abstract'], the code does not work. Maybe, I am missing something?

Comment: Updated the answer! Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for the update. The code is probably color-sensitive. It does not remove the pages that contain colorful words except the black.

Comment: I tested with Abstract in red. Worked just fine. Would be intresting to see your own file.